# Why will the following function input not work with the given AngularJS loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way that I can get another object inside of an object using a input parameter from a function. I have two different $scope variables I want to set for names, one for zone managers and another for construction managers. In this example I have looped inside of each object to grab the names. I would need to do this process twice, so I am not interested in repeating this numerous number of times so I create a function. The problem is that whenever I use "value.functionInputValue" I get an error saying that it cannot read from undefined. Can someone help me know where I have gone wrong?

JavaScript:

```
$scope.zones = [{ 
        zoneManagers: { 
        zone1: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        },
        zone2: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        },
        zone3: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        },
    constructionManagers: {
        zone1: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        },
        zone2: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        },
        zone3: {
            name: 'Name',
            phone: 1111111
        }
    }
}];


function namesFilter(zoneType)
{
    var allZoneManagerNames = []; 
        angular.forEach($scope.zones, function(value, key)
        {
            var zoneTypeArray = Object.keys(value); 
            if ( zoneTypeArray.indexOf(zoneType) != 1 ) 
            {
                angular.forEach(value.zoneType, function(value2, key2)
                {
                    if (allZoneManagerNames.indexOf(value2.name) == -1)
                    {
                        allZoneManagerNames.push(value2.name);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return allZoneManagerNames; 
}

$scope.allZoneManagerNames = namesFilter("zoneManagers");
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: As suggested by @Titus you need to use `value[zoneType]` to iterate over the array of zones. also check your json not sure if its a typo but in the json the constructionManagers seem to be part of zoneManagers. or was that the intention?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `value[zoneType]` instead of `value.zoneType` since `zoneType` is the `String` that you pass as a parameter to the function.

Also, as @mhodges mentioned, it should be `zoneTypeArray.indexOf(zoneType) != -1` instead of `zoneTypeArray.indexOf(zoneType) != 1` but, in this case, you can simply do the check like this:

```
if(value[zoneType]){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is one of many things wrong with this code. The other big thing to point out is that the OP is saying if indexOf() != 1.. it should be if indexOf() !== -1

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jahongirr/earw30xu/1/)

Your `$scope.zones` variable is a little complicated, so you have to do a nested lookup of object fields.

The fiddle is a little simplified version! and I removed the array because I thought it is not needed. As there is only a big object left (instead of an array), a check should be like this `zones[zoneType]`, instead of `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this code, both syntactically and logically, so I will try to point them out for you to see if it fixes your issues.

1) `$scope.zones.zoneManagers` is missing an ending `}` before `$scope.zones.constructionManagers`

2) You should be checking `if (value[zoneType])` not `if (...indexOf(zoneType) != 1)`

3) You should be iterating over `value[zoneType]` not `value.zoneType`

#### Updated Code Should Look Like This:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.zones = [{
    zoneManagers: {
      zone1: {
        name: 'zoneName1',
        phone: 1111111
      },
      zone2: {
        name: 'zoneName2',
        phone: 1111111
      },
      zone3: {
        name: 'zoneName3',
        phone: 1111111
      }
    },
    constructionManagers: {
      zone1: {
        name: 'constName1',
        phone: 1111111
      },
      zone2: {
        name: 'constName2',
        phone: 1111111
      },
      zone3: {
        name: 'constName3',
        phone: 1111111
      }
    }
  }];

  function namesFilter(zoneType) {
    var allZoneManagerNames = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.zones, function(value, key) {
      if (value[zoneType]) {
        angular.forEach(value[zoneType], function(value2, key2) {
          if (allZoneManagerNames.indexOf(value2.name) === -1) {
            allZoneManagerNames.push(value2.name);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return allZoneManagerNames;
  }

  console.log('Zone managers => ', namesFilter('zoneManagers'));
  console.log('Construction managers => ', namesFilter('constructionManagers'));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
</body>

</html>
```